# Set var in foreach to use later

Tags: c#, razor

I'm trying to set a value in a foreach but i get the error that it dosent exist in the current contect.

Here is my code;

```
    @{
        string sUsr = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Request.ServerVariables["AUTH_USER"].ToLower();
        var db = Database.Open("SQLServerConnectionString");
        var selectUser = "SELECT * FROM USERS WHERE username = " + @sUsr;

        }
    @foreach (var userid in db.Query(selectUser)) 
                            {
                                var sReg = userid.userdisplayname;
                                var sAns = userid.usersign;
                                var smail = userid.usermail;
                            }
 ...some html code etc.

    @sReg   <---- The name sReg dosent exist in the current context
```

If i try with the folowing code it works and Hello World is rendered in my webpage

```
    @{ var myMessage =  "Hello World"; }

 ...some html code etc.

    @myMessage
```

Comment: `@sReg` is indeed outside the scope of the `foreach`. You need to use it *inside* your foreach somewhere

Comment: You're using `foreach` which implies you're expecting *multiple* results. So, each of those results assigns (potentially) a *different* value to `sReg`. Later, outside of the loop, you attempt to access `sReg` - but which value? There's some unclear thinking here somewhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your code, so that sReg is defined outside the scope of the foreach loop. You can do this like:

```
var sReg;
@foreach (var userid in db.Query(selectUser)) 
{
    sReg = userid.userdisplayname;
    var sAns = userid.usersign;
    var smail = userid.usermail;
}
```

You can now use the (last) value of sReg outside the loop's body.

Variables defined in code only have a limited area in which they are available, which is commonly called the "scope" of a variable.
Read [this article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa691132%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) to learn more about scope in C#.

Please be also aware of the fact that you may get multiple results from your query (unless you are selecting with top 1 or such). In that case, your sReg variable would only contain the value of the last iteration, which may not be desirable for you. In this case, a List could come to the rescue: http://www.dotnetperls.com/list

Comment: Very good explained! Thanks. It worked lika a charm when placing the var outside of foreach.

Answer (score 1):

`sReg` in this context only applied inside your `foreach` loop.

The reason you're getting the doesn't exist in current context error is because it's not in scope.

If you wanted to proceed and do something with your `var sReg` you would have to perform whatever operation you would like to do within the loop, or declare it outside if need be.

Hope this helps